# Bring out inputstream from inputstream

Tags: java, android

i need to bring out inputstream from inputstream , for example inputstream A is 1024 byte and i need to bring out inputstream B from A of Hundred and fiftieth byte  to end , from certain offset to certain end . i search in google and stackoverflow ...Is there any solution available in java ??

Comment: Is it a ByteArrayInputStream or just exposed to you as a plain old InputStream ?

Comment: @SB no , its not ByteArryInputStream, its InputStream , i use Inputstream Because my file for input is long for example a long video file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "skip" to skip the first 150 bytes.
Here is an example:

```
byte[] buf = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
long skip = is1.skip(5);        
System.out.println(is1.read());
```

Comment: tanks for answer , but i cant use ByteArray because my code need to work with larg file and i cant use ByteArray For input. in android programming my problem is memory ...

Comment: Just use your preferred InputStream class :)
    InputStream is1 = //your inputstream;
    long skip = is1.skip(5);

Comment: Be aware that `skip()` might not actually skip anything at all: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)

Comment: True, but that won't happen if the stream is ok and larger than the bytes skipped (it simply reads n bytes). Also, the number of bytes skipped is returned, so the program can check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you have a `FileInputStream`, you can use `FileChannel.position()` to set where in the file that stream will read from.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("whatever");
FileChannel channel = in.getChannel();
channel.position(10);
```

This will *not* work with other types of streams.

Comment: thanks for your answer , i need inputstream , is changable FileChannel to FileInputStream Or InputStream ?